# SourceSafe, how to change user name I use it to login in to the file repository?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I've had a login I have used so far to login while I was opening c# solution.

For some time, suddenly VS hadn't asked me for my user credentials and later I discovered
that I am under: "Admin" account when checking in the files ...

I have no idea How I could change the user name for my previous one ...

Can anyone give ma a hint How I could do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check in all files that you check outed using Admin account. Then go to File/Source Control / Change Source Conrol and Unbind the project.

After unbinding, bind project. While binding VS askes you VSS user name.